# THREE.js texture tiling inconsistanly

Tags: 3d, three.js

I am working on a project where we have a 3D model with a material applied, the material is then tiled over the surface of the object, that is all working fine. However I am currently working on a story that adds a flat preview of the material to the app. To do this I am creating a scene, adding a `PlaneGeometry, creating a mesh using the plane and the material retrieved from the 3D model.

However instead of tiling nicely like it does on the 3D model I get weird tiling where the tiles appear to repeat at inconsistant sizes.

Here's a couple examples.

Here is a material as applied to the 3D model, everything looks fine. (Red lines point to the tile edges)

[image]

However here is that same material applied to a plane. If you look closely you'll notice the lines running across the image where it tiles, and also take note how the space between the lines varies switching from a thin tile to a thick tile intermittently. This happens on both axis. (Red lines point to the tile edges)

[image]

Now to further complicate things, applying different materials from our material library causes different tiling, in this case it's more noticeable.

Again on the 3D model it's good (Red lines point to the tile edges)

[image]

But here on the plane there are a lot of tiling issues, and here the lines are coving up details of the material making it look bad. (Red lines point to the tile edges)

[image]

Here's the raw texture file

[image]

Here is my code that creates the renderer and creates the plane with the material.

```
private addPlane(): void {
    let planeGeo: THREE.PlaneGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10);
    let plane: THREE.Mesh = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, this.viewService.getMeshesByPart(this.part)[0].material);
    plane.scale.set(10, 10, 10);
    this.scene.add(plane);
  }

  private createRenderer(): void {
    let container: any = document.querySelector('.properties-panel-canvas-container');
    if (!this.renderer) {
      this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        alpha: true,
        antialias: false,
        premultipliedAlpha: false,
        preserveDrawingBuffer: true
      });
      this.renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);
      this.renderer.setSize(167, 167);
      this.renderer.domElement.id = 'properties-panel-canvas';
      container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you post them at the same scale? Zooming in and out affects textures...

Comment: Yup I hadn't before because the 3D model can be zoomed and rotated and the preview is static and can not be changed by the user. There are lines from the tiling in both cases, but on the 3D model the tile size is consistent for every tile, while in the preview it varies from tile to tile.

Comment: I see patterns in the 3d image too (second to last in your post) just not as regular so it's not as obvious. I'd make a js fiddle, upload the raw texture and such.

Comment: I updated the images to show the lines I see which helps highlight the inconsistency I'm trying to fix.

Comment: Upload a raw texture too. And out of curiousity can you check what the value of `yourTexture.minFilter` is?

Comment: I added the raw texture file we use. I don't know how to find the minFilter since we use a custom shader to create the shaderMaterial that we apply to the `THREE.Mesh`.

Comment: Well, that image doesn't really tile that well even when i put it in photoshop, it's got a border. Do you get any errors about the texture not being power of 2? It's 250, so mip maps cant really work with that. Of the top of my head, i forgot what happens, does it get resized or it's filtering is changed. Either way, where you use the custom shader, you should have shader's uniforms, in there find the texture, log it's value, look at the `minFilter` property. I'm inclined to say that linearMipFilter should maybe take care of this, but i may be wrong.

Comment: We're using THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138973/discussion-between-pailhead-and-efarley).